# How do I anchor one side of axis limits?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame of positive x and y values that I want to present as a scatterplot in `ggplot2`. The values are clustered away from the point (0,0), but I want to include the x=0 and y=0 lines in the plot to show overall magnitude. How can I do this?

```
set.seed(349)
d <- data.frame(x = runif(10, 1, 2), y = runif(10, 1, 2))
ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
```

[image: Plot without (0,0)]

But what I want is something roughly equivalent to this, without having to specify both ends of the limits:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,2)) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,2))
```

[image: Plot with (0,0)]

Comment: I know this is an old question but I just ran into it question and there seems to be a better solution. Use the function `expand_limits(...)` specifying the limits you want to include. 
(probably a new addition which wasn't available a few years back)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option is to just anchor the x and y min, but leave the max unspecified

```
ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,NA)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,NA))
```

Comment: Ah, relevant documentation is in `ggplot2::xlim`: "If a `NA` value is substituted for one of the limits that limit is automatically calculated."

Comment: I've got `Error in if (zero_range(range)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` while trying this

Comment: @DavidArenburg I just tried again in a clean R session and it worked fine. Tested using `ggplot2_1.0.0` with the sample data above.

Comment: Interesting, it was probably added on the last version

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a bit hacky, but it works for standard `plot` also.

Where `d` is the original dataframe we add two "fake" data points:

```
d2 = rbind(d,c(0,NA),c(NA,0))
```

This first extra data point has x-coordinate=0 and y-coordinate=NA. This means 0 will be included in the xlim, but the point will not be displayed (because it has no y-coordinate).

The other data point does the same for the y limits.

Just plot `d2` instead of `d` and it will work as desired.

If using `ggplot`, as opposed to `plot`, you will get a warning about missing values. This can be suppressed by replacing `geom_point()` with `geom_point(na.rm=T)`

---

One downside with this solution (especially for `plot`) is that an extra value must be added for any other 'per-data-point' parameters, such as `col=` if you give each point a different colour.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `expand_limits(x=0,y=0)`, i.e.:

```
set.seed(349)
d <- data.frame(x = runif(10, 1, 2), y = runif(10, 1, 2))
ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0)
```